# Postbox is unable to open emlx files from Finder

Tags: email, osx-lion, postbox

I'm running Postbox 3.0.3 on Mac OS X Lion and when I'm trying to open an email messages from Finder (where Postbox is my default app for Mail Messages) I'm getting an empty message with an attachment for the message  itself (a recursion). This does not happen with Mail app.

Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I've never seen it working properly.

Comment: Please add a screen shot to your question.